# How to call a C# method in a C# class from Java?

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface

```
[DllImport(@"CeSmLm.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

private static extern UInt32 CePrnGetTotPaperRemainingUsb(
                  int intDev, 
                  ref UInt32 dwNumCmPaper, 
                  ref UInt32 dwSysErr);
```

This is the method in C# class, I wanna call it in a Java Class. It's possible to call it ?

Comment: Have a look  Hope it is help full to you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13093/C-method-calls-within-a-Java-program

Comment: It's actually an import from a native DLL, so you actually want to call that, not any C# method.

Comment: Yes, actually I want import a DLL file which write in C language fromJava. But I use System.loadLibrary(""); 
I also can't call the method in the Dll file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-wrap-a-Csharp-library-for-use-in-Java

Also you can also use ikvm for java/.net interop

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594632/IKVM-NET-in-Details